# An easier way for me to calculate the distance , But does it always stand true?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, distance

When can I say that the distance is equal to $d=\int^{t_2}_{t_1}|V|dt$ , Where V is the velocity and it's given in terms of time and $t$ is the time , You might wonder  why I'd need this ; it's because this can be written directly on the calculator without needing to use this formula $|S_2-S_1|+|S_3-S_2|$ Where $S_1$ is the displacement at $t_1$ , But this formula($d=\int^{t_2}_{t_1}|V|dt$) sometimes gives wrong numbers , Why?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by distance. Distance is one thing and displacement is another.  Also what you mean with $|S_2-S_1| +|S_3-S_2|$?

Comment: $S_1$ is the displacement at $t_1$ , What do you mean by "what do you mean by distance" I meant distance for sure not displacement as displacement is $(S_3-S_1) $

Comment: What are $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$? Can you give an example where the formula you wrote down gives the wrong answer?

Comment: So is $S_1$ the position at time $t_1$? What do you mean with "displacement at $t_1$? Displacement with respect to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance is correctly defined as:
\begin{equation}
d=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}|V(t)|dt
\end{equation}
But if $x(t)$ is the position at time $t$ (I think this is what you mean by $S_i$), then:
\begin{equation}
|x(t_2)-x(t_1)|=\left|\int_{t_1}^{t_2}V(t)dt \right|
\end{equation}
And in general:
\begin{equation}
\left| \int_{t_1}^{t_2}V(t)dt\right| \neq\int_{t_1}^{t_2}|V(t)|dt
\end{equation}
The alternative formula for distance that you propose $|S_2-S_1|+|S_3-S_2|$ can't reproduce distance. You can't say anything about the total distance travelled from the initial and final positions alone in general. The two expressions coincide only if during the intervals $[t_1, t_2]$ and $[t_2, t_3]$ velocity has a definite sign. In that case it means that you're only going forward or only going backwards and the inequality I wrote becomes an equality.

Comment: Just a note on mathjax: you can also use `\left` and `\right` for the "absolut value" vertical lines to cover the height of the expression.

Comment: @noah Thanks, I edited my post.